# How to avoid Instanceof operator usage?

Tags: java, android

I have a class i.e. A.java and two sub classes B and C which extends class A.
suppose following structure of classes.

```
  class A implements Base{
   @Override
   void m1(){
      //some code
    }
  }

  Class B extend A{
   ABC m2(){
   }
  }

 Class C extend A{
    XYZ m3(){
      }
    }
```

Now I'm implementing following way at multiple places. Everytime using instanceOf operator, is hectic. How can I avoid usage of instanceOf operator.

```
Class Test {
public void getData(Base aData){
    A a = aData;
   if(a instance of B){
   ABC aBC = ((B)a).m2();
   abc.someData();
   }
   else
   XYZ xYZ = ((C)a).m3();
   xYZ.someOtherData();
 }
}
```

Comment: You could add an abstract method to A and implement it in B to do one thing and in C to do another thing.

Comment: By having a `m()` inside `Base` that everybody can / has to override.

Comment: @khelwood but return type of m2() and m3() is different.

Comment: But you're ignoring the return type in your `Test` class. So what does it matter? Give your abstract method return type `void` and discard the return values.

Comment: @luk2302 what about the return type if I''ll add inside the Base

Comment: @khelwood return type is matters. Based on that I've to access different class variable.

Comment: Then post code that actually shows how you need to use these methods, otherwise how can anyone advise you how to do it differently?

Comment: You *may* have to look into "java generics".

Comment: @khelwood edited post code. Please have a look.

Comment: I don't think that's made it any clearer. You could call `someData()` inside your `void` overridden method as well.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the code currently in your question:

> ```
> if (a instanceof B) {
>     ABC aBC = ((B)a).m2();
>     abc.someData();
> } else {
>     XYZ xYZ = ((C)a).m3();
>     xYZ.someOtherData();
> }
> ```

you can avoid `instanceof` using an abstract method in your `A` base class like this:

```
abstract class A implements Base {
    ...
    abstract void m();
}
```

or in your interface like this:

```
interface Base {
    ...
    void m();
}
```

that you implement like this:

```
class B extends A {
    ABC m2() {
        // whatever you have here
    }

    @Override
    void m() {
        ABC abc = m2();
        abc.someData();
    }
}

class C extends A {
    XYZ m3() {
        // whatever you have here
    }

    @Override
    void m() {
        XYZ xYZ = m3();
        xYZ.someOtherData();
    }
}
```

Then you can replace your `instanceof` block with

```
a.m();
```